# DFHWS DATA CONTSINER not showing DFHRESPONSE data

Tags: web-services, mainframe, cics

I am developing a CICS web service requestor application to consume a distributed web service. I used the web services assistant DFHWS2LS to transform the wsdl to copybooks successfully.

I have no problem issuing the PUT CONTAINER and INVOKE SERVICE api commands, but when I issue GET CONTAINER to get response, the DFHWS-DATA container still contains the request (data sent in put container) data only.

DFHRESPONSE container has the response from distributed system but CICS is not converting it into my application copybook structure.

Comment: adding this as a comment for @Remko: Since I'm currently working with CICS web services, I might be able to answer your question, however, I'm not allowed to comment (yet)...

Could you include some of your code please. And are you sure the EXEC CICS INVOKE SERVICE command is executed succesfully?

Answer (score 0):

Be certain to check the `RESP` and `RESP2` values returned by the `INVOKE SERVICE` API.

Take a look in the TD queue mapped to `CSSL` (the default is the `MSGUSR DD`) for your CICS region. This is where CICS logs messages when it runs into an error while processing your SOAP request. Look for messages prefixed `DFHPI`.

Comment: Thanks cschneid... Found the issue in MSGUSR.